# Undefined index Model Name on delete

Tags: php, cakephp

I am getting the following error while deleting data in a Cakephp app:

```
Undefined index:  Image [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1477]
Model::updateCounterCache() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1477
Model::delete() - CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 1842
ImagesController::delete() - APP/controllers/images_controller.php, line 67
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 86
```

Here is my code, which is getting this error:

```
$this->Image->delete($image_id);
```

I have confirmed that $image_id is not null and is correct, also confirmed that error is fired by this particular line. I am inside the images_controller. I am using Cakephp 1.3.

Here is my image model code:

```
  class Image extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Image';

   var $belongsTo = "User";

    function afterFind($results) 
    {
       /*some custom afterfind work here */
    }
  }
```

Image is being deleted from the database, but I keep getting this error.

======================================= EDIT
Complete code for the function:

```
function delete() {

            $this->checkAuth();

            $user_id = $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

            if(!empty($this->data))

            {

                $image_id = $this->data['Image']['id'];

                $image = $this->Image->find("first", array("conditions"=>array("Image.id"=>$image_id)));

                if($image) {

                    if($image['Image']['user_id']==$user_id){

                        $this->Image2->delete_image($image['Image']['image_path'],"upload");
                        //echo "image id:".$image_id;
                        $this->Image->delete(intval($image_id));

                        $this->set("success","1");

                        $this->set("msg","Image deleted successfully."); 

                    }

                    else {

                        $this->set("success","0");

                        $this->set("msg","You do not have permission to delete this image."); 

                    }

                }

                else {

                    $this->set("success","0");

                    $this->set("msg","Cannot find image."); 

                }

            }

            else

            {

                $this->set("success","0");

                $this->set("msg","No data posted"); 

            }

        }
```

There is nothing in the view as we output json from this.

Comment: Could it be some file writing permission error?

Comment: I'd have to guess it's an issue with some code we're not seeing.  If it's deleting the image, that means it DID run and get passed that line at least once.

Comment: FYI, I tried to comment this line and the error disappeared, then I removed the comment and it appeared again. So, it seems that the trouble somewhere with this line only. I will check what I am doing before and after it!

Comment: Try putting a debug before and after it, then an exit;  That will keep it from running more than once, and if you get the debug, then the error, you'll know it's 1) for sure w/ that line, and 2) on the first go-through.

Comment: Added the complete code. Please note I am not a good programmer :P

Comment: Ok, I kept a debug before and after (debug 1 and 2), and then exit. I saw the debug 1, then error and then debug 2 and then end as it exit.

Comment: nope, there are only two functions in the model, afterFind and imageexist, afterFind calls imageexist, which checks if the image exist, thats it.

Comment: One more thing, I noticed: Notice (8) Undefined index:  Image